# Как правильно написать Try and Catch

Tags: java, try-catch, матрицы

```
package matrix;

/**
 *
 * @author Den
 */

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(3, 3);

        try {
            m1.put(0, 0, 100);
            m1.put(0, 1, -5);
            m1.put(0, 2, 0);
            m1.put(1, 0, 100005);
            m1.put(1, 1, -20);
            m1.put(1, 2, 64);
            m1.put(2, 0, 199910);
            m1.put(2, 1, -35);
            m1.put(100, 1000, 128);
        } catch (MatrixIndex)
            {

            }

            System.out.println(m1.toString());

            Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m1);

            System.out.println(m2.toString());

            System.out.println(m1.equals(m2));

            Matrix m3 = new Matrix(2, 2);

            m3.put(0, 0, 10);
            m3.put(0, 1, 53);
            m3.put(1, 0, 20);
            m3.put(1, 1, 106);

            System.out.println(m3.toString());
            System.out.println(m1.equals(m3));
        }

    }



 }
```

второй файл кода если хотите понять:

```
package matrix;

/**
 *
 * @author Den
 */
public class Matrix {
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private int[][] data;

    Matrix(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        data = new int[row][col];
    }

    Matrix(Matrix matrix) {
        this.row = matrix.getRow();
        this.col = matrix.getCol();
        data = new int[row][col];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                data[i][j] = matrix.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public int get(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    void put(int row, int col, int value) {
        data[row][col] = value;
    }

    private int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    private int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Matrix m = (Matrix) obj;

        if (m.getRow() != row || m.getCol() != col) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (data[i][j] != m.data[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        out.append("Matrix:\n[ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                out.append("\n");
                out.append("  ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                out.append(data[i][j]);
                if (j == col - 1) continue;
                for (int k = 0; k < getMaxLength() - getIntLength(data[i][j]) + 2; k++) {
                    out.append(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        out.append("  ]");
        return out.toString();
    }

    private int getMaxLength() {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                int k = data[i][j];
                if (k > max) {
                    max = k;
                }
            }
        }
        return getIntLength(max);
    }

    private int getIntLength(int i) {
        return String.valueOf(i).length();
    }
```

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться через try catch?

Comment: чтобы не выходило за границы индекса, чтобы выводило только матрицу 3х3. Допустим если ввести (23,23) должно выводить ошибку так как она не подходит на 3х3

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите в вопросе пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Зачем вам что-то обрабатывать с помощью try catch, если там нет никакого исключения. Можно обойтись просто проверкой(валидацией) и если не подходит число, то присвоить дефолтное и все

Comment: в задании написали)

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно ловить java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    ...
}
```